# Magento2 : Child theme catalog module layot xml is not overrided

Tags: magento-2.1.8

I have created two themes first is parent and second is a child to change the design of product page.

I want to set different layout for some product layout so I have created the child themes. A child theme inherits from its parent theme.

I have to override the layout in a child it is taking on parent layout it is not taking the child theme layout.

Please give an idea if anyone gets this.

Following is the `theme.xml`

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Child themes</title>
     <parent>Magento/Parent</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

And i want to change the `catalog_category_view.xml` layout for child theme. All the templates files are overwriting but layout file are not working.

Comment: maybe share some more information, e.g. files

Comment: Updating the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `<parent>` tag as `<parent>Magento/blank</parent>`
Now your theme.xml is looking like below,

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Child themes</title>
    <parent>Magento/blank</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

**You have set parent  as Magento/Parent and There are not any theme related Magento/Parent by default.**

Run command,

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: I have already try but not getting solutions.